# How to post array of objects in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post array of objects in JSON data using Postman , but unable to create the object,how will i achieve it?Here is my code

````
```
models.py
```

class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

class ClassDaySlot(models.Model):
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,related_name='dayslot_classes')

    day = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)



class ClassTimeSlot(models.Model):
    day_slot_id = models.ForeignKey(ClassDaySlot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,related_name='my_class_timeslot')
    start_slot_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_slot_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```
serializers.py
```

class ClassUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class_day = serializers.ListField()
    class_time = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = Classes

    def create(self, validated_data):
        dayslot_validated_data = validated_data.pop('class_day', None)
        timeslot_validated_data = validated_data.pop('class_time', None)
        classes = Classes.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if dayslot_validated_data:
            for day_slot in dayslot_validated_data:
                created_day_class = ClassDaySlot.objects.create(**day_slot, class_id=classes)
                if timelot_validated_data:
                    for time_slot in timeslot_validated_data:
                        ClassTimeSlot.objects.create(**time_slot, day_slot_id=created_day_class)
        return classes

I have to post json data in postman exactly like this:
    {
    "class_day":[{
                "day":"friday",
                "class_time":[
                        {
                        "start_slot_time":"08:00:00+0000",
                        "end_slot_time":"09:00:00+0000"
                        }

                ]           

            }]
    }
````

I am getting this error: `"ClassDaySlot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_time'". if i give "class_time" outside "class_day" list, it works but i don't want that, what i want is to post array of "day" and "class_time"` objects which i mentioned in the above JSON format.Any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pop `class_time` before passing it to `ClassDaySlot.objects.create`.

```
class ClassUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class_day = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = Classes

    def create(self, validated_data):
        dayslot_validated_data = validated_data.pop('class_day', None)
        classes = Classes.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if dayslot_validated_data:
            for day_slot in dayslot_validated_data:
                timeslot_validated_data = day_slot.pop('class_time', None)
                created_day_class = ClassDaySlot.objects.create(**day_slot, class_id=classes)
                if timelot_validated_data:
                    for time_slot in timeslot_validated_data:
                        ClassTimeSlot.objects.create(**time_slot, day_slot_id=created_day_class)
        return classes
```